# Fetching data on page load and assigning it to select optins in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a simple form, where I have a **select type form**. This form has ***no*** options on creation, because I want to **dynamically add them** from the back end.
Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-container fluid>
      <b-row align-h="center">
        <b-col cols="14"
               sm="10"
               md="8"
               lg="6"
               xl="4">
            <b-form-group id="exampleInputGroup3"
                          :label="$t('modellingPage2.modeltypeLabel')"
                          label-for="exampleInput3"
                          :description="$t('modellingPage2.modeltypeDescription')">
              <b-form-select id="exampleInput3"
                             :options="modeltypes"
                             required
                             v-model="form.modeltype">
              </b-form-select>
            </b-form-group>
          </b-form>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </b-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import AuthenticationService from '.././services/AuthenticationService'

  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        form: {
          modelname: '',
          modeltype: '',
          typesArray: ''
        },
        modeltypes: [
          {text: 'Model', value: null},
          this.testopen
        ],
        show: true
      }
    },
    methods: {
      async getUnits () {
        try {
          const response = await AuthenticationService.getUnits()
          this.typesArray = response.data.ModelType
        } catch (error) {
          this.error = error.response.data.error
        }
      }
    },
    created () {
      return this.getUnits()
    },
    computed: {
      testopen () {
        return this.typesArray.forEach(element => element)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

It is an *Axios Get request* inside the AuthenticationUser. However the problem is the **local usage of data**. I cannot push the elements from the array inside my **modeltypes** data.

Comment: Your select is using "modeltypes" for the options, but your getUnits call is setting typesArray.

Comment: what is this.testopen?

Comment: Thank you that was the answer. I had been stuck for a day and not realized it. If you post it as an ansher I can confirm that :)

Comment: You may consider deleting the question then.

Comment: Posted it as an answer - but I won't be offended if you delete too. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select is using "modeltypes" for the options, but your getUnits call is setting typesArray.